# how to transpose a row into column

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table that has three columns

```
cell
stime(contain date and time)
tchdrop
```

I have stime between `starttime` and `endtime` that is selected by user .It means it should be variable.I want to transpose rows into column and only `stime` and `tchdrop, cell as it is .` how should i do .kindly help me and give me a proper solution. if user select stime between 10 to 20 and date is select by user it may be any two date. it maybe 10days or 1months. it means stime be a  variable it has any no of values.
eg.
If i have o/p like this.

```
cell             stime                   tchdrop
M            2012-04-10 00:00:00:000      10
Q            2012-04-10 01:00:00:000      20
z            2012-04-10 01:00:00:000       0
.                 .                        .
.                 .                        .
r            2012-04-20 20:00:00:000       0
```

and now i want to result like this

cell  tchdrop   2012-04-10   2012-04-11 2012-04-12 ..................2012-04-20
M             10   0              4             10.............
Q             20   .              .             ...........
z 
.             .    .              .             .....................
.             .
.
r             s

Comment: Can you show us what result you are excepting?

Comment: Try searching this site for [`[sql-server] dynamic pivot`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql-server]+dynamic+pivot).

Answer (score 0):

read about PIVOT and UNPIVOT [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

An example [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/)